# Problems with JQuery change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have the following `.change()` function:

```
$('#accmenu').change(function() {
    $(".insightsgraphs div").hide();
    $(".insightsoptions input").removeClass("green");
    $("#newLikes").one('click', function () {
        $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'newLikes.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
            function(response) {
                var json = response.replace(/"/g,'');
                json = "[" + json + "]";
                json = json.replace(/'/g,'"');
                var myData = JSON.parse(json);
                var myChart = new JSChart('dailyNewLikes', 'line');
                myChart.setDataArray(myData);
                myChart.setSize(960, 320);
                myChart.setAxisNameX('');
                myChart.setAxisValuesColorX('#FFFFFF');
                myChart.setAxisNameY('');
                myChart.setTitle('Daily New Likes');
                myChart.draw();
            }});
        return false;
    });
    $("#newLikes").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
        $('#dailyNewLikes').toggle();
        return false;
    });
    $("#unlikes").one('click', function () {
        $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'unlikes.php', data:$('#ChartsForm').serialize(), success:
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#dailyUnlikes").html(response);
            }});
        return false;
    });
    $("#unlikes").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
        $('#dailyUnlikes').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

that any time I change the option from the `accmenu` select to hide all the divs corresponding to `insightsgraphs` class and remove the green class from all the inputs of it. After I select one of the four options that I have everything is working like it should but if I choose another one the buttons on click will not become green and also the divs will not be shown. it doesn't run this piece of script:

```
$("#newLikes").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
    $('#dailyNewLikes').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

that should toggle between the green and red color of the button and also it should hide or show the div. the ajax call is made properly for the second option for example but the button doesn't get the green class and the respective div is not shown. What is the problem with my code? What is causing this issue? Another odd thing is that the 3rd option is working but the 4th not...

Comment: You shouldn't bind event handlers **inside of** event handlers...

Comment: What Ian said. Try moving your click handlers outside the scope of your .change() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked your code. It seems you put some of the events inside the "change" event. The issue here when the change has been triggered all the event inside will re-run again. So this will cause a problem on your functions. Better to separate those events outside of the change and create a closure function so that you can acquire those data that you want from outside.